# Invalid XML when using XmlWriter in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I am trying to create the following XML document-

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

            XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(fs);

            w.WriteStartDocument();
            w.WriteStartElement("People");
            w.WriteStartElement("Person");
            // loop over checked elements
            foreach (var xxx in checkedListBox1.Items)
            {

                w.WriteAttributeString("Name", textBox1.Text);
                w.WriteAttributeString("GamerTag", textBox2.Text);
                w.WriteAttributeString("Wins", textBox3.Text);
                w.WriteAttributeString("Losses", textBox4.Text);
                w.WriteAttributeString("Ratio", textBox5.Text);

                // get id of this match
                id = checkedListBox1.Text.Substring(1, 3);
                // call the function at the service to download the type of struct we require
                res = client.photo(id);
                format = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                w.WriteElementString("Picture-id", res.ToString());
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex))
                {
                    // do something
                    w.WriteElementString("Game", checkedListBox1.Text);
                }
                w.WriteEndElement();
            }
            w.WriteEndElement();
            w.WriteEndDocument();
            w.Flush();
            fs.Close();
```

However on debugging I getback this error -

> Token StartAttribute in state Element Content would result in an invalid XML document.

On the line - `w.WriteAttributeString("Name", textBox1.Text);`

I have checked for spaces etc however not sure why this is cropping up, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Employ `using` on your `FileStream` to ensure disposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `w.WriteStartElement("Person");` should be part of the loop.

After all, you call `w.WriteEndElement()` in the loop as well.

Comment: @leppie: Yeah, the comment already was an answer so I moved it. ;)

Comment: Seems the clown above you copied your comment. IIRC the text was identical. Makes me a sad panda.

Comment: @leppie: No, the text is not 100% identical. Apart from that, the error really is so obvious, it doesn't need copy/paste to reach the same conclusion. ;)

Answer (score 2):

As Tomalak pointed out, the `w.WriteStartElement("Person");` should be part of the loop.
Apart from that, it is not `nice` to create the XML on the fly inside your GUI. You should consider building seperrate classes that hold your datastructure.

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GamerTag { get; set; }

    // all other attributes go here
}

class People 
{
    public Person[] Persons { get; setM }
}
```

fill those classes either by hand or by [binding them to the controls](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c8199) and generate your XML from thoses classes. And also consider changing the names of your controls. It is always nice to know what a control represents without finding it in a form first. `textBox1`is not really meaningful, `NameTextBox` is better choice, don't you think?

Comment: I see your point @esskar im not entirely sure I think the XML may be poorly structured due to the way I have written it out. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line `w.WriteStartElement("Person");` has to be written in the loop. You don't start an element in the loop, but you end it.